# How to Resize background image to match the Layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have a question, how do you resize a background image in android studio to match the whole layout for example:
I have a drawable that is landscape by default, but my layout is horizontal, I want to decrease the width and increase the height of thag photo to match thr layout, how do I do that??

Answer (score 1):

You need to scale your image, add this property and change the fitCenter by the one that corresponds to your criteria `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`.

Comment: Fit center doesn't cover the whole layout tho, most of the times it zoom out and prioritize the image to be zoom out but it won't cover the whole layout

Answer (score 1):

There are android scale types which you can refer **CENTER, CENTER_CROP, CENTER_INSIDE, FIT_CENTER, FIT_END, FIT_START, FIT_XY and MATRIX.** which can be used as per your requirement. But as you mentioned you can try `android:scaleType="center_crop"` which crops the image a bit but covers the whole screen

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```